# Is a convex cone generated by a bounded convex closed set containing the origin closed?

Tags: convex-cone

Consider a closed **bounded** convex set in the space of Lebesgue integrable functions L^P that contains the origin. Is a convex cone generated by the set closed?

Comment: The compactness is still need to be established in my case. Hence, I would prefer to have an answer without it. However, if there is a clear positive answer with compactness, I will try to establish compactness.

Comment: Could you give a reference to the "trivial" part?

Comment: ah sorry. It is not true, if it contains the origin, even assuming compactness. Cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination

Comment: Thank you! I somehow missed the Wiki example. This is very helpful. I see the need for a separate specific proof for the closedness property in my case. –